# Custom Angular setup for MIT library/project

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, rest, express, angular-cli

Hi I need your help trying to figure it out something.

First a little background, I was used to code in Django, it was fast to code and good, but times change and Node is taking over most of new apps, then I move to Express a couple of years ago, however I still miss a lot of the Django functionality, then I start coding a little library to help me with common tasks, then start growing until the current point where you have a core library and plug-able “apps” to do recurrent tasks, like notifications, auth and more, or at least that’s the plan.

Right now an app works something like this:

./controllers (All renders)

./endpoints (Restfull API endpoints)

./models (Static and DB models)

./public (Public files)

./style (Scss styles with bootstrap injected)

./views (Default templates, distributed with the app as example, loaded by default)

…/…/views (Custom views to rewrite the default ones from the app)

On start, JSloth compile everything for you and run the server (hot reload included):

[image: JSloth start]

Now, that works fine using an static multipage environment, but I will love to use Angular for that, changes will be needed but I want you guys to lead me in the right direction.

So far I have 2 ideas:

1- Split Routes/Html apps and Restful/Endpoints, then basically use an standard set up on that kind of apps with webpack and AngularSSR.

- The big downside is, you can’t give an out the box frontend implementation for apps.

2- Figure it out a way to provide an Angular app for each JSloth app, in this way if you install/copy the auth app you will be provided of user lists, interfaces to update your profile, etc.

- I’m thinking that may be a problem talking about performance because in this way you will have a lot of Angular apps, am I wrong?
- I need a easy way to allow the final user to share footers and headers at least, maybe even styles or scss variables for colors, in that way it will not look like a huge change.

Do you have any other option? Any better idea?

Thank you so much for the help, this is the repository: https://github.com/chrissmejia/JSloth

Edit 1: Forgot to add the models folder